# Data type restriction in REST Web service method

Tags: .net, web-services, rest

Is there any restriction on the data types that the input parameter that is present in URI has to be string in REST Webservice?

I am creating a REST Webservice. The method has an input paramter Id and this present in the URI as well.
If I change type to integer, it generates error when calling it.

```
Operation 'Get' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'id' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF REST in .net 4 is not capable of doing this conversion, however WCF Web API can.  http://wcf.codeplex.com

This has nothing to do with any constraints of REST it is purely a limitation of the implementation framework.